# Plot: line colors when using assumptions

Tags: plotting, color

I want to vary a parameter via assumptions in a simple line plot and assign a different line color to each parameter value. Unfortunately all lines are the same color. I also tried to use Evaluate[], but no change at all. Any hint? Here's a minimal example:

```
Plot[Sin[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] + 2 T \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> 1, 
       T -> {1, 2, 3}}, {\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{Black, Red, Blue}}]
```

Comment: try `Plot[Evaluate[
  Sin[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] + 2 T \[Omega]] /. {\[Omega] -> 1, 
    T -> {1, 2, 3}}], {\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi], -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Blue}]`?

Comment: That did the trick; don't know what I did wrong before hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Evaluate` on the function list in the first argument of `Plot`.
2. Use `{Black, Red, Blue}` as the `PlotStyle` option setting. (Not `{{Black, Red, Blue}}`.)

[image]